# Tomcat 8 StaticMembershipInterceptor & uniqueId attribute

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

For the following in a Tomcat 8 `server.xml`, what is the exact purpose of the `uniqueId` attribute:

```
<Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.StaticMembershipInterceptor">
   <Member
     className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.StaticMember"
     port="5678"
     host="tomcat02.example.com"
     domain="cluster"
     uniqueId="{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}"
   />
 </Interceptor>
```

I've read conflicting things about it in various places.

Also, what is the difference between a `<Member>` & a `<LocalMember>`?

Is the `<LocalMember>` for the tomcat that is using the `server.xml` in which it's defined?  If so, then I imagine there should be at most 1 `<LocalMember>` per `<Interceptor>`.

If the info in [this mailing list post](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/200710.mbox/%3C47277409.3080800@hanik.com%3E) is correct:

1. wouldn't `uniqueId` only make sense for a `<LocalMember>`, and not for a `<Member>`?
2. wouldn't `uniqueId` only really need to be unique for the triplet of `host`, `port` & `uniqueId`, not across all `hosts` and/or ports?
3. if I only ever plan to run one member of a cluster per `host` & `port`, should the `uniqueId` for that pair change every time that server is stopped and restarted?
4. will there be problems if I reuse the same `uniqueId` across server restarts?
5. will there be problems if I use the same `uniqueId` for different `host` & `port` combos in the same `server.xml`?
6. if I must use different values for `uniqueId` in different circumstances, is there any way for tomcat to generate a random one for me, e.g., by leaving out the `uniqueId` attribute, or by setting it to a special value like `random`?

Comment: Did you get any further with this? I can't find any doco on LocalMember at all.

Comment: I haven't really investigated further.  Will post an answer if I find useful info.

Answer (score 0):

My experience doesn't match that in the mailing list post. And sadly I don't know the answers that I want to know.

- 3, 4 and 6. The uniqueId for a given server doesn't need to change over time.
- 5. will there be problems if I use the same uniqueId for different host & port combos in the same server.xml?

I believe so - the uniqueId should only apply to one server.
(What I haven't worked out is if the uniqueId is 'universally unique' to the server it is on, or to the cluster. I.e. If Server1's uniqueId for Server 3 is {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15} should Server2's uniqueId for Server3 also be {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}, or something else)